# wrong escape single quote in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, escaping

I got a ORACLE SQL query which creates a directory. Now I want to build a plsql block, which creates a directory. But I am not able to successfully escape the single quotes to make it run. Can anyone help me please?

```
create or replace directory "SOURCE_DIR" as '/my/path/to/dir/' ;
```

inside my plsql function:

```
execute immediate 'create or replace directory "SOURCE_DIR" as ''/my/path/to/dir/'' ';
```

Comment: The escaping actually looks right. What error are you getting?

Comment: Your `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` statement executes without error on my Oracle 11g database (with and without the trailing space).

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why I cant make it run in my SQL developper, as I tried it directly on SQL plus, it works. However I finsihed my script and finally ended up with this snippet:

```
 -- create directories 
 execute immediate 'create or replace directory "SOURCE_DIR" as ''' || i_src_dir_name  || '''';
```